# Does a file move operation over SAMBA preserve the inode number?

Tags: rsync, backup, samba, inode

If I have a directory exposed over a SAMBA share and a user, from either a Linux or Windows system, moves a file from one place to another on that share, does SAMBA know to ask the operating system for a move operation and keep the inode number?

Similarly does renaming a file on a SAMBA share keep the inode number consistent?

Bonus question that might need to be its own question: I use rsync to create differencing backups within the server (CentOS 7) from the device to a different backup device. Can the differencing backup track inode numbers on the device and the backup, to itself correctly track the file move/rename?

**Update: 24/01/2018**

On my installation, a move operation does in fact preserve inode number.

- Windows 7 x64 Professional
- Centos 7 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64
- Samba version 4.4.4

Are there any other qualifying system configuration specifics I should list above?

Comment: It sounds like you already have a samba share and a client, I would say try `ls -i $file` (prints the inode of the file) before and after each operation to see.

Comment: Funny answer. In a sample space of one, whatever the result I wouldn't know if it were reliable or to-be-expected.

Comment: Well I didn't post an answer, just a comment in the hopes of leading you. Are you performing a statistical analysis? Just curious? Or absolutely need the inode to remain the same for an application to work (which sounds like a dreadful app)? If not 1 or 3, you can probably just test it to see for yourself.

Comment: I'd like to know the expected behaviour by design, something reliable. Then if my system doesn't do that thing then I know where to look for issues. Also I don't know if SAMBA's behaviour is dependent on the client operating system or even version, or if it is designed to be absolutely consistent. It seemed possible different client's operating systems may issue different commands to represent a move. Like I say in the question, the ultimate goal is having a robust backup system, and that relies on knowing what user's systems might do to the files.

Comment: On your comment 'sounds like a dreadful app', is there a more robust way of establishing true file identity?

Comment: Normally an app wouldn't need to be aware of the inode, it's handed a filepath from either the user or config, why should it be concerned with "true" file identity? It's not normally an app's job to check your files, unless its something that specifically checks your filesystem (which would make sense to concern itself with inodes).

Comment: The final application is a file server that can make robust and lightweight differential backups of networked drives, irrespective of what housekeeping operations are performed by its users via SAMBA.

Comment: That context would be beneficial to your question I think, that this is for the purpose of performing backups over network. Will your backup app be logging the inodes of each file? Why not use something preexisting like rsync on the SAMBA host?

Comment: I tend to feel questions can get clouded with too much case-specific context and become less valuable to others. Nonetheless, the backup does indeed occur using rsync, but the backup destination starts with hardlinked copies of a last backup and rsync performs a differencing copy. (The hard links are why I'm interested in inode identity.) So for this use case, any files moved on the source at a time between backups causes me headaches, wasted space from duplicate backups. I am investigating what the constituent technologies can/will do.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if the Samba share's Linux top directory has two or more mounted Linux filesystems somewhere underneath it in the directory hierarchy.

If you then move something from under one of those sub-mounted filesystems' mountpoint to the other within the same Samba share, I'm pretty sure you can count on the Linux inode changing.  You should test it out to be sure, though.